# A phrase to express the step taken after another

Tags: phrases, expressions

Let's say that I have a goal to achieve and I take many steps. Step A (done), and B(currently working on). Can I say this:

> I did the step A. Then, I **continued upon** that step by taking the
>   step B.

I'm skeptical about the phrase in bold. Is this true? Can the phrase be improved?

Comment: "Take the next step."

Comment: You progressed from step A to step B

Comment: "I **followed** it with step B." HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've taken a step, it's done. So, you can't say that you're continuing that step after it's finished.

However, given that your goal has many steps, you could phrase it differently:

> I took step A. Then I continued **toward my goal** by taking step B.

Each step brings you closer to your goal.